# Matplotlib Box and Whisker with Points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 5 separate genes. Each gene has a set of points associated with it. As such, I decided to make a box and whisker plot to compare these different points between the genes. However, for each gene, there is one special value associated with it. Let's call it the age of the gene. I would like to visualize how this age value compares to the other points for each gene. Is the age higher than all of the points? Lower? Smack dab in the middle? How can I best do this with matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a [boxplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) and a [plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) of the age on the same axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# fake date
genes = 10*np.random.rand(10,5)
age = 10*np.random.rand(5)

# plot the data
plt.boxplot(genes)
h, = plt.plot(range(1,6),age,'go',ms=15) # used a large marker size so these points show up.

# add a legend
plt.legend([h],['age'],numpoints=1)

plt.show()
```

[image: example boxplot]